# Why it doesn't continue inserting into table after it gets correct?

Tags: c#, sql

Focusing on

> cmd.Parameters.Add("@Jumlah", result);

Im Trying to insert multiple datarow into table in single button with sqlinsertcommand for each textbox = 1 row, sqlcommand must run if each textbox.text > 0 then execute the command

and why after it gets 0, it stop the next command and stop inserting.. I want it continue to next insert

but only insert if it has value > 0 of each textboxes..

if its 0 skip it to next insert

How do i do that? sry with my english.. i appreciate any help!

```
foreach (TextBox txt in pnl_Jus.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToArray())
{
    int result = 0;
    if (int.TryParse(txtJusM.Text, out result) && result > 0)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd13 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Transaksi (idStruk,Product_Name,Jumlah,TotalHarga,Tanggal_Transaksi) VALUES (@idStruk,@Product_Name,@Jumlah,@TotalHarga,@Tanggal_Transaksi)", con);
        cmd13.Parameters.Add("@idStruk", lblidstruk.Text);
        cmd13.Parameters.Add("@Product_Name", chkminum6.Text);
        cmd13.Parameters.Add("@Jumlah", result);
        cmd13.Parameters.Add("@TotalHarga", Tjmelon);
        cmd13.Parameters.Add("@Tanggal_Transaksi", lbldate.Text);
        cmd13.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        return;
    }

    if (int.TryParse(txtJusA.Text, out result) && result > 0)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd14 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Transaksi (idStruk,Product_Name,Jumlah,TotalHarga,Tanggal_Transaksi) VALUES (@idStruk,@Product_Name,@Jumlah,@TotalHarga,@Tanggal_Transaksi)", con);
        cmd14.Parameters.Add("@idStruk", lblidstruk.Text);
        cmd14.Parameters.Add("@Product_Name", chkminum7.Text);
        cmd14.Parameters.Add("@Jumlah", result);
        cmd14.Parameters.Add("@TotalHarga", Tjalp);
        cmd14.Parameters.Add("@Tanggal_Transaksi", lbldate.Text);
        cmd14.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        return;
    }

    if (int.TryParse(txtJusJ.Text, out result) && result > 0)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd15 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Transaksi (idStruk,Product_Name,Jumlah,TotalHarga,Tanggal_Transaksi) VALUES (@idStruk,@Product_Name,@Jumlah,@TotalHarga,@Tanggal_Transaksi)", con);
        cmd15.Parameters.Add("@idStruk", lblidstruk.Text);
        cmd15.Parameters.Add("@Product_Name", chkminum8.Text);
        cmd15.Parameters.Add("@Jumlah", result);
        cmd15.Parameters.Add("@TotalHarga", Tjj);
        cmd15.Parameters.Add("@Tanggal_Transaksi", lbldate.Text);
        cmd15.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        return;
    }

    if (int.TryParse(txtJusS.Text, out result) && result > 0)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd16 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Transaksi (idStruk,Product_Name,Jumlah,TotalHarga,Tanggal_Transaksi) VALUES (@idStruk,@Product_Name,@Jumlah,@TotalHarga,@Tanggal_Transaksi)", con);
        cmd16.Parameters.Add("@idStruk", lblidstruk.Text);
        cmd16.Parameters.Add("@Product_Name", chkminum9.Text);
        cmd16.Parameters.Add("@Jumlah", result);
        cmd16.Parameters.Add("@TotalHarga", Tjs);
        cmd16.Parameters.Add("@Tanggal_Transaksi", lbldate.Text);
        cmd16.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just remove the return statements

Comment: What is the purpose of your foreach loop if you never use the iterator variable _txt_ in your code?

Comment: I'd recommend you familiarize yourself with a debugger. You'd get a quick and easy answer for this problem.

Comment: `return` causing that, so it exist once `return` is executed

Comment: On top of everything that's been said, you don't need the `.ToArray()` after the `OfType`.

Comment: @Sefe I'm not even sure what the loop is for - `txt` is never used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `return`. Remove them. However while we are at it, you could also reuse the connection, and chuck everything appropriately in a `using`

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(""))
{
   conn.Open();
   int result = 0;

   if (int.TryParse(txtJusM.Text, out result) && result > 0)
   {
      using (SqlCommand cmd13 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Transaksi (idStruk,Product_Name,Jumlah,TotalHarga,Tanggal_Transaksi) VALUES (@idStruk,@Product_Name,@Jumlah,@TotalHarga,@Tanggal_Transaksi)", con))
      {
         ...
      }
   }

   if (int.TryParse(txtJusA.Text, out result) && result > 0)
   {
      using (SqlCommand cmd14 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Transaksi (idStruk,Product_Name,Jumlah,TotalHarga,Tanggal_Transaksi) VALUES (@idStruk,@Product_Name,@Jumlah,@TotalHarga,@Tanggal_Transaksi)", con))
      {
         ...
      }
   }

   if (int.TryParse(txtJusJ.Text, out result) && result > 0)
   {
      using (var cmd15 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Transaksi (idStruk,Product_Name,Jumlah,TotalHarga,Tanggal_Transaksi) VALUES (@idStruk,@Product_Name,@Jumlah,@TotalHarga,@Tanggal_Transaksi)", con))
      {
         ...
      }
   }

   if (int.TryParse(txtJusS.Text, out result) && result > 0)
   {
      using (var cmd16 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Transaksi (idStruk,Product_Name,Jumlah,TotalHarga,Tanggal_Transaksi) VALUES (@idStruk,@Product_Name,@Jumlah,@TotalHarga,@Tanggal_Transaksi)", con))
      {
         ...
      }
   }

   conn.Close();
}
```